# Not able to start project as asp.net Core (Razor App)

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have installed VS 2017 community edition and i am trying to create ASp.net Core 2.0 (Razor Page) but i am not getting that template when i create the project as show in this [tutorial](http://gunnarpeipman.com/2017/05/razor-pages/)

What i get is show in below image
[image]

I am new to .Net Core and want to start learning .Net Core.

Comment: not so up to date tutorial. try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/

Comment: @tazih, what is the best way to get started for people who are from .net webform background & with no experience in MVC

Comment: Try to learn about MVC first to grab the concept. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412(v=vs.108).aspx this link will provide you the overview to understand MVC. But you don't need to work on MVC and then Core again. You can implement MVC in Core project. so, try to grab concept of MVC first from above and then follow this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET Core with Razor Pages is the third option in your screenshot:

[image]

However, unless you will create extremely simple web applications, you should skip it and go to the full ASP.NET MVC (fourth option). While Razor Pages is very new (only some months old), MVC has been pretty much the same for years, and allows for much more development.

Comment: I am just try to get started I am not that much into development as of now i am more of webform guy just want to keep updated with the latest, i know i am behind as i have not worked on MVC due to other project in asp.net webform etc..

Comment: I would suggest you to first start with MVC then. Razor Pages are a new weird attempt at mixing WebForms with MVC, and there are no good reasons to learn its weird syntax. If you read the GitHub posts, you'd see it's not very liked and it probably won't last long

Comment: Besides, ASP.NET 4.5 MVC 5 and ASP.NET Core MVC are pretty much same, only Core having newer, easier ways to do some things.